# API versioning using Openshift API gateway

Tags: openshift, api-gateway, api-versioning

We have a requirement where we need to have multiple versions of the same API with few changes in it, but we cannot change the URI whatsoever.

URI versioning : api.example.com/v1/resource

Domain versioning : apiv1.example.com/resource

(Request) parameter versioning: GET /something/?version=0.1 HTTP/1.1

In these example, we might have to change or add version numbers in the URI.

Is there anyway through openshift to do API versioning and not change the URL.?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to look at Red Hat's API Management solutions.

If you are on OpenShift Dedicated, there are some bundled entitlements of the hosted [Red Hat OpenShift API Management](https://www.redhat.com/en/technologies/cloud-computing/openshift/openshift-api-management). If you are on self-managed OpenShift, you'd want to look at [3Scale API Management](https://www.redhat.com/en/technologies/jboss-middleware/3scale). Essentially the same product/features, just managed vs. not.